# c program that calculate the area of the circle

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   float radius, area;

   printf("\nEnter the radius of Circle : ");
   scanf("%d", &radius);

   area = 3.14 * radius * radius;
   printf("\nArea of Circle : %f", area);

   return (0);
}
```

I've written the above program to work out the area of a circle given its radius but I'm getting very strange values and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Learn more on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use C++ I/O instead of the C library and this particular problem will go away.

Comment: Your title asks about C your tag is C++, if you decide on one of the two you will more easily find help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using an *integer* format specifier `%d` to scan into a `float` point variable `radius`. This is actually undefined behaviour <sup>(a)</sup>, and you should be using `%f` to scan in `float` variables.

The standard is explicit that this is a requirement (quote below extracted from `C11 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /12`, and C++ defers to the C standard for legacy stuff like this):

> `a,e,f,g` - Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or NaN, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtod`
>   function. ***The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to floating.***

---

Of course, if this is a C++ question, you would be better off using the facilities from `iostream` rather than `stdio/cstdio`. The type safety of C++ will generally avoid this issue since behaviour adapts to the types rather than you having to manually specify things.

That could be as simple as something like:

```
float radius;
std::cout << "\nEnter the radius of Circle : ";
std::cin >> radius;
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> One of the things that *might* happen is that `scanf` happily places the integer into the memory where the floating point value exists. Unfortunately, they tend to use different encoding schemes (such as two's complement against single precision IEEE754) so will end up with the exact symptoms you describe.

Of course, being undefined behaviour, one of the *other* things that might happen is to total breakdown of causality, followed by complete destruction of the universe :-)

And, yes, that's hyperbole, but it's meant to stress how bad it is to rely on undefined behaviour. Obviously  the consequences won't *really* be that bad, but it's often a good idea to assume they will be.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I'm struggling to find the "not nice" bits, though I'll freely admit my first answer was probably *not* as nice as it could be - it's since been made more so in the various edits, I think. I'm more than happy to make changes if anyone wants to offer any suggestions.

Comment: No probs, Yunnosch, I'm happy to change those things regardless of how minor you think they may be. Hopefully, the updates make the answer better. Cheers.

Comment: In my opinion they do. Also, I am impressed by your way of handling my input.